# Can't use a controller with Steam In-Home Streaming

Tags: steam, steam-in-home-streaming

I'm streaming from my Windows PC to my Linux laptop and trying to use a wireless PS3 controller. The controller works fine when playing games running on the laptop but doesn't get recognized when using In-Home Streaming.

The controller works with games that I've tried to stream (Tomb Raider, Mad Max, etc.) when I run them under Linux, so it's not a problem with the games not supporting it.

Is there some confusion going on between my two computers while streaming? Do I have to pair the controller to the streaming PC and not the laptop for it to be recognized as an input device? Or, maybe, it's not possible to use a PS3 controller on the laptop because the streaming PC doesn't recognize the input?

Comment: Have you checked the official support article on in-home streaming yet? https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-RIAV-1617#nocontrollerinput

Comment: I've used in home streaming to a Windows HTPC with controllers just fine.  They were wireless Xbox 360 controllers using the wireless adaptor.  I'm thinking if you had a wired 360 controller, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the official support article on in-home streaming](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-RIAV-1617#nocontrollerinput):

> ### My game controller input doesn't affect the game
>
> If your game
> controller isn't recognized by any game, check to see if Steam Big
> Picture recognizes it in the controller settings on the client
> computer. You may need to configure your controller there in order to
> use it for streaming. Some games use raw input instead of XInput or
> DirectInput and are not yet supported.

Comment: This way it recognizes inputs when it's connected through USB but still not wirelessly, even though I can setup the controller when not connected.